# SharePoint VS workflow emailing to a SharePoint group

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have a code activity that sends an email in a VS workflow. It simply sets the 'To' property to the name of a SharePoint group in the site collection.  However, only the 1st person in the group gets emailed.

Any ideas why this is happening?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does your group contain anything other than just users (ex: distribution lists, ad groups)?

If this is still a problem and you need to be able to send to a SharePoint group, I would recommend writing a custom workflow Action that would gather the emails of all the users in a specified group (you can find many tutorials online on how to make a custom action).

Comment: Nope, just straight up users.  I ended up itterating the group and extracting the email addresses.  Thanks for response!!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was not even emailing the first user.  I decided to extract the user emails programatically instead.  Works fine.